# Angular Service method with subscribe get result on component variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service with a method.
This method subscribes in the service and not in the component.
The result is in `message.content`.

Here is the code:

Service Method:

```
myMethod() {
    this.socket$.subscribe(
        (message) => {
          console.log(`${message.content}`);
        }
    );
}
```

App Component

```
contentVariable;
ngOnInit() {
    this.myservice.myMethod();
}
```

My question is...how do I get message.content from the service into contentVariable in my component?

Comment: i think your solution like this service `return this.socket$.subscribe()` component `this.contentVariable = this.myservice.myMethod();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use promises to return a value from the subscribe method.

```
myMethod() {

    return new Promise(resolve=>{ 
       this.socket$.subscribe(
        (message) => {
          resolve(message.content);
        }
    );
   });

  }
```

In your component.ts, use the promise `then()` method to assign the value to `contentVariable`

```
contentVariable;

  ngOnInit() {


    this.myservice.myMethod().then(val => this.contentVariable = val);


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be two options.

as per your code, you have to return the message result so that you can access into your component method.

In service,

myMethod() {

```
this.socket$.subscribe(
    (message) => {
      return message.content
    }
);
```

}

Edit:

If you are making any api call in service, for ex, you can subscribe like below mentioned:

service:

url = 'localhost:3000';

api = `${url}/api/get/users`;

getUsers() {

return this.http.get(api)

}

component: 
ngOnInit() {

this.service.getUsers().subscribe((res)=>{

console.log(res)

})

}

Comment: How so I call it from the component?

Comment: This would return the `Subscription` and not the value

Answer (score 0):

Simply return message.content from your service.

**Service side:**

```
myMethod() {
this.socket$.subscribe(
    (message) => {
      return message.content;
    });

}
```

**Component side:**

```
contentVariable: any;

ngOnInit() {

   this.contentVariable = this.myservice.myMethod();
}
```

Comment: This would return the `Subscription` and not the value

Comment: This is not a problem, we can subscribe contentVariable to get its content.

Comment: FYI, this is the behavior of your code https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rte9nv

Answer (score 0):

I would subscribe from the component, however, you can set a property in your service:

```
myMethod() {

    this.socket$.subscribe(
        (message) => {
          this.content = this.message.content;
        }
    );

  }
```

and use that property of the service in your component.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of Subject to achieve this.

Service Method:

```
content$ : Subject<string> = new Subject<string>()
myMethod() {
    this.socket$.subscribe(
        (message) => {
          this.content$.next(message.content)
          console.log(`${message.content}`);
        }
    );

  }
```

App Component

```
contentVariable;

ngOnInit() {   
    this.myservice.content$.subscribe(content => this.contentVariable = content)
    this.myservice.myMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your service method needs to return the observable. You can use `tap` to view the data without subscribing, that will allow your service to log it as you were trying to do. The component then subscribes to the returned observable.
**Service**

```
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

// class name, constructor, etc omitted

myMethod() : Observable<{content: string}> {
    return this.socket$.pipe(tap((message) => console.log(`${message.content}`)));
}
```

**Component**

```
contentVariable;
ngOnInit() {
    this.myservice.myMethod().subscribe(_ => this.contentVariable = _.content);
}
```